# Typecasting in Scala

Tags: scala, casting

I have an alphanumeric field in an RDD of type AnyRef.

- Case1: If it's 99898, I want to cast it as Long
- Case2: If it's 0099898, I want to cast it as String
- Case3: If it's AB998, I want to cast it as String.

I am trying this:

```
try {
  account_number.asInstanceOf[ Long ])
} catch {
  case _: Throwable => account_number.asInstanceOf[ String ])
}
```

But in this, I miss the case2, because 0099898 is converted to 99898. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a note: a RDD of type AnyRef isn't very helpful. Anyways you can change that somehow?

Comment: Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this field is `AnyRef` I wouldn't expect `AnyVal`s there at all (like `Long`) - Scala's numbers are not equal to Java's numbers. At best you can have there some instance of `java.lang.Numeric` (e.g. `java.lang.Long` which is NOT `scala.Long`).

But to turn it into `Long` you would have to use pattern matching (with type matching or regexp pattern matching) and conversion (NOT casting!) to

```
val isStringID = raw"(0[0-9]+)".r
val isLongID = raw"([0-9]+)".r

account_number match {
  case isStringID(id)    => id // numeric string starting with 0
  case isLongID(id)      => id.toLong // numeric string convertible to Long
  case l: java.lang.Long => l.toLong // Java's long
  case _                 => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected long or numeric string")
}
```

However, I would find that completely useless - right now you have `Any` instead of `AnyVal`. You could expect it to have `Long` or `String` but it's not represented by the returned value so compiler would NOT have any information about the safe usages. Personally, I would recommend doing something imediatelly after matching e.g. wrapping it with Either or creating ADT or passing it to function which needs String or Long.

```
// can be exhaustively pattern matched, or .folded or passed, etc
val stringOrLong: Either[String, Long] = account_number match {
  case isStringID(id)    => Left(id)
  case isLongID(id)      => Right(id.toLong)
  case l: java.lang.Long => Right(l.toLong)
  case _                 => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected long or numeric string")
}
```

You cannot use `.asInstanceOf` to turn `AnyRef` to `Long` because neither is subtype or supertype of another, and this operation would always fail.

```
     Any
   /     \
AnyVal  AnyRef
  |       |
 Long     |
   \     /
   Nothing
```

`.asInstanceOf` would only make sense if you were moving vertically in this hierarchy, not horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you have is:

```
def tryConvert(s: String): Either[Long, String] = {
  Try(s.toLong).filter(_.toString == s) match {
    case Success(value) =>
      Left(value)
    case Failure(_) =>
      Right(s)
  }
}
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/jHdREMsPQByAQaAHsqbEDg/2).